# How to control output from Twisted-trial tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, output, twisted, buildbot

### How to control output from Twisted-trial tests?

I have looked up for different solutions, but I'm quite new to testing, so I can't find a fitting solution or can't use it correctly.

In general, I try to make autotesting system for my project like BuildBot. But BuildBot doesn't fit me because it reacts only to "On change sources" hook from Mercurial and I want to use other hooks too.

On **[THIS](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-buildfactories.html)** page from BuildBot documentation I found this information:

> One advantage of trial is that the Buildbot happens to know how to
> parse trial output, letting it identify which tests passed and which
> ones failed. The Buildbot can then provide fine-grained reports about
> how many tests have failed, when individual tests fail when they had
> been passing previously, etc.

**Does it mean that there is no way but to parse information from test-output?**

### Other possible solutions?

Besides, I looked up in Twisted documentation and found this class **[IReporter](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.trial.itrial.IReporter.html)**.

**Is it a solution and if it is, how can I use it?**
**If it isn't, are there any other solutions?**

P.S. Please, note, that tests have already been written, so I can only start them and can't modify source code.

Comment: Huh?  What do you want?

Comment: From some mercurial hook, I start a series of twisted-trial-tests. I want to somehow get results from this tests, analyze them and run some code according to this results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format output from trial arbitrarily by writing a reporter plugin.  You found the interface for that plugin already - `IReporter`.

Once you write such a plugin, you'll be able to use it by adding `--reporter=yourplugin` to your `trial` command line arguments.

You can see the list of reporter plugins that are already available on your system using `trial --help-reporters`.  If you have `python-subunit` installed then you'll see `subunit` which is a machine-parseable format that might already satisfy your requirements.  Unfortunately it's still a subunit v1 reporter and subunit v2 is better in a number of ways.  Still, it might suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the solution I was looking for. Interesting thing that I have already encountered subunit, when I tried to represent results in Jenkins, but didn't pay much attention to it.